# how can find angular velocity of CD which is $\omega_{CD}$. With the length of $AB,BC,CD$ are fixed.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, classical-mechanics, maple

[image]

we have AB can spin round A with angular velocity $\omega_0$. Now,
how can find angular velocity of CD which is $\omega_{CD}$.
With the length of $AB,BC,CD$ are fixed.

This is my effort:

Firtly, I attach a  coordinate axis $OXY$ at $A$, and I find the position of $B$ and $D$ like bellow:

$x_B=AB\cos (\omega_0t)$

$y_B=AB \sin(\omega_0t)$

$x_D=AD$

$y_D=0$

Secondly, I found the position of C by two equations:

$(x_C-x_B)^2+(y_C-y_B)^2=BC^2$ and $(x_D-x_C)^2+(y_D-y_C)^2=CD^2$

and I tend to find the value of angle $\angle{CDA}$ to find $\omega_{CD}$

but I stuck at two equations above that have solution's position of $C$ because I  receive 2 solutions and I don't know what is the right?

My purpose is solving this problem by Maple so i gonnna show my code:

```
restart;

xB := AB*cos(omega0*t);
yB := AB*sin(omega0*t);
xD := AD;
yD := 0;

pt1 := (xC-xB)^2+(yC-yB)^2 = BC^2;
pt2 := (xD-xB)^2+(yD-yC)^2 = CD^2;

solve({pt1, pt2}, [xC, yC]);
```

And I don't know command to choose 1 solution in maple,too.

So can you help me? Or if you have documents related about this, could you share me.
 Thank you so much!

Comment: the other solution makes the polygon non convex, so I guess we have to choose the one with the greater $y_C$. To choose use sol[1], or sol[2].

Comment: Also you have a typo in pt2, should be $x_C$.

Comment: thank you so much but with other length, the shape ABCD can be always non convex :( i think